# How should I write my WHERE clause in SQL Server for the following case?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table with two columns `Date` and `User` and contains the following rows:

```
    **Date        User**
    2009-02-20  Danny
    2009-02-20  Matthew
    2009-02-15  William
    2009-02-15  Abner
    2009-12-14  Joseph
    1900-01-01  Adam
    1900-01-01  Eve
```

Given a date, how should I write my WHERE clause to return a list of users for that date, or if no users users were found for that date, return a list of users for the next earlier date. For example, if the given date is '**2009-02-19**', the users list returned should be **William** and **Abner**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT User
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyDate = (SELECT MAX(MyDate) FROM MyTable WHERE MyDate <= '2009-02-19')
```

Comment: you have an extra )... it should be 
WHERE Date = (SELECT MAX(MyDate) FROM MyTable WHERE MyDate <= '2009-02-19')

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT [User] FROM myTable WHERE Date =
  (SELECT Max(Date) FROM myTable WHERE Date <= '2009-02-19')
```

Comment: How's this get voted up when I wrote the exact same thing earlier? *scratches head*

Comment: Like you need the rep cletus ;)

Comment: I'm reminded of a Simpsons quote where Homer says, "Lisa, a guy who's got lots of ivory is less likely to hurt Stampy than a guy whose ivory supplies are low."

Comment: @cletus: it wasn't exactly the same originally, yours had a Select * in there briefly ;)  Still you got the answer tick and now more votes.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM [MyTable] t
INNER JOIN
   ( 
      SELECT TOP 1 [Date]
      FROM [MyTable]
      WHERE [Date] >= @TargetDate
      ORDER BY [Date]
   ) d ON t.[Date] = d.[Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select Name
from UnknownTable
where [Date] = 
    (select Max([Date]) 
     from UnknownTable
     where [Date] <= '2009-02-19')
```

This assumes there are no time components to your date values.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this

SELECT TOP 2 [Date]
      ,[User]
  FROM [LearningDatabase].[dbo].[Users]
  WHERE [Date] = '07/15/2009'
  OR [Date] < '07/15/2009'

Comment: OP only wanted records with earlier dates if no record was found on date asked for.